# Parse Server on Azure: Classes & Collections

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, parse-server

I have migrated our Parse app to Azure but have run into cost issues due to the number of Classes we have in Parse translating 1 to 1 as Collections on Azure. Having so many Collections is overkill and too expensive for us, but I need to have these various Classes in Parse. So - my question - is there a way to implement Parse server on Azure in such a way that every Class just shares one Collection on DocumentDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To coerce Parse to store all user-defined classes in a single collection, you'd need to actually modify Parse, as it's currently mapping `class` to `collection`, by design (specifically: Based on MongoDB collections).

So, TL;DR - no, you cannot store all of your classes in a single collection.

Comment: Thank you for your response, David.  This is unfortunate because it means Azure is not a viable (too expensive) platform for us - I was hoping to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem a week ago.
I'm in a correspondence with the DocDB guys about this.
Hoping they can find a pricing solution for Parse+DocumentDB, otherwise its a dead-end.